# Wallpaper changes don't survive restart

Tags: 16.04, 64-bit, desktop-background, system-settings, appearance

When I change the wallpaper image using System Settings > Appearance, the new wallpaper displays correctly. But after I restart, it reverts to the old wallpaper. This is true for any new image that I choose, as far as I can tell.

Note that before the change, the file in ~/.cache/wallpaper/ shows the old image; after the change, it shows the new image; and after restart, it again shows the old image.

Perfectly possible that through tinkering I have broken something, but I don't even know where to begin troubleshooting. Also, I have Googled everything I can think of and failed to come up with anything relevant. Running 16.04 64-bit.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**Please read the forum post before doing anything here, to prevent the corruption of your system.**

According to [here](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=228152), this command might fix it.

`find /home/$SUDO_USER ! -user $SUDO_USER -exec chown $SUDO_USER:$SUDO_USER '{}' \;`

Apparently, this occurs because of the bad ownership of your directory.

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if file/directory permissions/ownership are the problem, but I don't really understand the explanation at the linked-to URL. What directory are we talking about here? And what should the ownership/permissions be?

Comment: The directory we are talking about is the `~/.cache/wallpaper/` directory, and the command I gave sets the `/home/your_username` permissions to your account - so that you own them. Your account should have full permissions for everything inside your directory (referred to with `~`)

Comment: Thanks, Modelmat. I do own all folders and files inside my home directory, including ~/.cache/wallpaper/, with 700 and 600 permissions respectively. I have tried setting them to 755 and 644, but the result is the same: The wallpaper and the file in ~/.cache/wallpaper/ update when I select a new image in the control panel, but both revert to the old image after restart.

Comment: Ok. I don't really have a fix at the moment.